# How can I color horizontal lines in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Both markdown mode and Org mode allow you to insert a number of dashes on an otherwise empty line (at least three in markdown mode, at least five in Org mode), that are rendered as horizontal rules in the exported output.

In markdown mode, the dashes become green in the markdown buffer.

Would it be possible to obtain the same behavior in an `org-mode` buffer, where the dashes become colorful?

---

https://orgmode.org/manual/Horizontal-Rules.html

> 12.9 Horizontal Rules:
> A line consisting of only dashes, and at least 5 of them, is exported
> as a horizontal line.

Comment: It is possible, but you'd have to bring the subject to the org-mode mailing list. From my cursory look, org doesn't define any customizable face for these dashes.

Comment: Are you talking about appearance in the Org mode file buffer? If so, are you talking about displaying the five dashes in green? Or do you really want to display a green horizontal rule that runs across the page? BTW, if what you want is to change how the buffer looks, the link reference is irrelevant since it's about export, so it ends up confusing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not clearifying it, I want its apperance in the Org mode file buffer, while I am editing into it.

Comment: I edited but if the edit is wrong, feel free to revert the edit (or edit some more).

Comment: BTW, I just tried and in my case, nothing happens to the dashes in markdown mode. Have you tried with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Ah `emacs -Q` keeps it as white. I Could you please try it with `(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)` or dracula theme (https://github.com/dracula/emacs/tree/62c960dbfe9cadc72784878c1cff20389895e193)

Comment: I think `(markdown-markup-face :foreground "blue" :weight bold)` is the responsible line

Comment: @NickD Please see https://list.orgmode.org/87h7e5dtbb.fsf@ucl.ac.uk/T/#t

Comment: @NickD I get following answer: `you can add a rule like this in an org-mode hook:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '(("^-\\{5,\\}"  0 '(:foreground "red" :weight bold))))
#+END_SRC`

Comment: If it works for you, make that an answer and accept it. Putting it in a comment does not help.

Comment: @NickD It worked for me! I added the answer hope it is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the Professor John Kitchin`s original solution from: https://list.orgmode.org/87h7e5dtbb.fsf@ucl.ac.uk/T/#t

---

> you can add a rule like this in an org-mode hook:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords
             nil
             '(("^-\\{5,\\}"  0 '(:foreground "green" :weight bold))))))
```

> that will make a line starting with at least 5 - be green and bold in color.